# Visualizing derivative of a matrix-valued function of a matrix variable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, visualization

Apologies if this is not at an appropriate level for this site or if it's too broad/scrambled of a question, but I was wondering how best to visualize a matrix-valued function of a matrix variable?

For some context: in my single variable calculus class, we were taught that the derivative of $f(x)$ at a point $x = a$ is $f'(a)\in\mathbb{R}$. This represents the slope of the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)\vert_{x = a}$. The equation of this tangent line is $y = f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)$, and this is the *best* linear approximation of $f(x)$ near $x = a$.

In my analysis class, we were taught that the derivative of a map $f:U\to F$, where $U\subseteq E$ is open, $x\in U$, and $E,F$ are complete normed linear spaces, is a continuous linear map $\lambda=f'(x):E\to F$  satisfying $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)(h)+|h|\psi(h) $$ with $\lim_{h\to 0}\psi(h)=0$ and $\psi(0)=0.$ There is no confusion here. This definition is in accordance with our definition from single variable calculus, it's a special case as expected, where the standard matrix of this linear transformation (in the one dimensional case) is the $1\times 1$ matrix $[f'(a)]$. If we consider the special case of our scenario where $E$ and $F$ are Euclidean spaces rather than arbitrary complete normed linear spaces, i.e. for $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$  at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then the derivative $Df(a)$ is an $m\times n$ matrix $Df(a) = \left[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}( a)\right]$, or the Jacobian of $f$ at $a$.

On our exam, we were asked to compute the derivative of $f:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) $ given by $f(x)=x^3$. This was a fairly straightforward computational task, however I have been stuck about how to visualize/understand my answer. I know you could just say that $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ are isomorphic as complete normed linear spaces, so think of it in terms of the framework that has already been established.

My question is: I know how to visualize/conceptualize this exam question when $f$ is a real-valued function of a real variable, but in the case from the exam is there a way to understand it in terms of what a linear map actually does (some combination of rotation and scaling) or where the vectors that comprise the matrix live with respect to the function (in some tangent subspace would be my intuition, but I'm not sure since I don't have that level of background in such a subject)? Is there a meaningful way to answer/subject to address my question or is the whole matter moot since even for a $3\times 3$ matrix, that would correspond to a function of $9$ variables, which we cannot visualize?

Comment: How would you propose to visualize the derivative of a function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^4$, which at a point $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ is itself a linear map $Df_{\alpha}: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^4$ (which we can canonically identify with an element of $\Bbb{R}^4$)? But can you really visualize $\Bbb{R}^4$? Personally, I just like to "collapse" everything down to one-dimension. Here, we have $E=F= M_{n}(\Bbb{R})$, and $f:E \to E$ is some map. So, for the purposes of drawing on paper, I simply draw $E$ as a 1-dimensional subspace, so that I can draw the graph of $f$ on a piece of paper.

Comment: If you want to keep track of where everything lives, then one way to view it is to define $Tf:U \times E \to f[U] \times F$ by $Tf(x,v) := (f(x), Df_x(v))$. We may call $Tf$ the "tangent map", and the way to think about it is that $Tf$ takes in an element $(x,v)$, which we like to think of as the tangent vector $v$ "based at the point $x$", i.e $v \in T_xE := \{x\} \times E$ is an element of the tangent space of $E$ at $x$, and $Tf$ maps it to the tangent vector $(f(x), Df_x(v)) \in T_{f(x)}F := \{f(x)\} \times F$. So, $Tf$ is then a map between tangent spaces.

Comment: @peek-a-boo i liked that second explanation, it certainly helped! I guess I am tripping up on the fact that a matrix is a representation of a linear transformation wrt a certain basis, but its also a vector, so its hard for me to visualize a linear transformation "existing" in one place like one would draw a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example, if that makes sense. Regardless, it helped!

Comment: Another way to view the situation is that you have a curve $\gamma: \Bbb{R} \to E$ with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$; in other words the curve $\gamma$ passes through the point $x$ with velocity $v$. Then, the tangent map $Tf$ maps the curve $\gamma$ to the curve $f \circ \gamma:\Bbb{R} \to F$, which passes through $(f \circ \gamma)(0) = f(x)$, with velocity vector $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = Df_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma'(0)) = Df_x(v)$.

Comment: This geometric way of thinking of tangent spaces as the space of all "velocities of curves" can easily be generalized to abstract smooth manifolds (more precisely the tangent space can be defined as a certain equivalence class of smooth curves). But anyway, This probably goes a bit too far astray from what your initial question was, but hopefully it gives you a glimpse of what one could expect in a more abstract setting. Your first question though about transformations as a vector amounts to asking "how can I visualize a vector space $E$". For this, I just think of it as a "generalized arrow"

Comment: @peek-a-boo it definitely gives me a glimpse of what to expect, I thought manifolds might be involved just from cursory conversations about them, but I have no formal education in them, so your comments certainly give me answers to look forward to. Not really related to my question, but does your curve comment above have anything to do with integral curves and differential equations? or am I stretching? but it still helps, so thank you!

Comment: Strictly from the perspective of defining tangent spaces, no this has nothing to do with the integral curves from ODEs. The integral curves of ODEs arise as follows: given a vector field $X$ (i.e at each point of my manifold... which you can think of as $\Bbb{R}^n$ for simplicity, we have an arrow) the question you ask is can I find a smooth curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma'(t) = X(\gamma(t))$? i.e such that the velocity at each point of the curve coincides with the vector already prescribed. So really, the concept of integral curves relies on having already defined the tangent space somehow.

Comment: @peek-a-boo very interesting, always nice to learn something new, so thank you!